# Gamemaker's xprevious is the same value as x... Same thing happens for the y variabbles

Tags: game-maker

So I'm making a tower defense game but for some reason the enemies (which are following a path) have the same xprevious value as their x value. The same is true for their y variables. This also happens when the enemy is not on a path. I double checked that I'm not modifying the x and y previous variables anywhere. Is this a bug in GameMaker?

Thanks,
Philip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GameMaker [automatically stores](http://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/movement%20and%20collisions/movement/xprevious.html) `x` and `y` to `xprevious` and `yprevious` just before `Begin Step` event.

If object moves using paths, then position (`x` and `y`) of the object will be [changed](http://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/000_using%20gamemaker/events/index.html) after `Step` event and before `End Step` event. So, before `End Step` coords and previous coords will be same, but after `End Step` it will be different.